# How can I generate a list of a given users audiences?

Tags: 2010, audience-targeting

I have a webpart that works off audiences to target content to users in a global portla (content comes form all over) how can I give users the ability to see which audience they are currently in? For usability, I would like to add a link that shows the audiences the user currently belongs to so they can understand why they see what they see in the list.

In sharepoint 2010 BTW

Answer (score 0):

```
AudienceLoader objAudLoader = AudienceLoader.GetAudienceLoader();
AudienceManager.IsCurrentUserInAudienceOf(objAudLoader, audience, false)
```

The AudienceLoader belongs to Microsoft.Office.Server.Audience namespace and documented here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.audience.audiencemanager.iscurrentuserinaudienceof.aspx

you also see this link: http://blogs.prexens.com/pages/category.aspx?Name=Audiences

Hops this helps